# How to capture image statistics

Tags: html, apache, cpanel, awstats

I host images locally on my server for use on eBay and other sites. I would like to track the hourly and daily usage of these images. My server has cPanel installed.

I've tried adjusting AWStats to track images; but the configurations I have trialled only display the usage per month.

Any ideas how I can get tracking like this happening?

Comment: damn it took me 10 minutes to get your problem... since AWStats is perfectly fine for your daily tracking with nearly no effort: http://wiki.colar.net/daily_stats_with_awstats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other sites allow it, you could use a PHP-file that loads the image. In the file itself you can fetch and store any stat you'd like.

If PHP (or simular language) isn't allowed (it probably isn't) you could use AWstats, because it does what you want. Alternatives are:

- Analog
- Webalizer
- W3Perl
- Visitors
- Piwik
- Obsessive Website Statistics
- Etc

You'd have to check out yourself it they support what you need.